# xsd.exe C# file to XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XML file that I used to create an XSD File and from there generated the C# code.

However, during development I had to make some changes to that C# file.  Is there a way I can use the xsd.exe tool to convert that C# file back into an XSD file?  I'm hoping to avoid having to go and manually edit the XSD File.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C# file directly you cannot go back to the XSD file (not by using xsd.exe).

You can build back the schema from the type constructed in the C# file:

`xsd.exe yourdll.dll /t[ype]:TypeYouWantASchemaFor` or

`xsd.exe yourExe.exe /t[ype]:TypeYouWantASchemaFor`

See the *DLL and EXE File Options* section from the xsd [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: right, and remember. . . the schema you arrive at, is just one possible schema that the document conforms to.  It will not be completely general, obviously.